# Grep: unexpected results when searching for words in heading from man page

Tags: grep, man, special-characters

I'm running into weird behavior when trying to grep a man page on macOS. For example, the Bash man page clearly has an occurrence of the string `NAME`:

```
$ man bash | head -5 | tail -1
NAME
```

And if I grep for `name` I do get results, but if I grep for `NAME` I don't:

```
$ man bash | grep 'NAME'
$ man bash | grep NAME
```

I've tried other uppercase words that I know are in there, and searching for `SHELL` yields nothing whereas searching for `BASH` yields results.

What's going on here?

**Update**: Thanks for all the answers! I thought it worth adding the context in which I ran into this. I wanted to write a bash function to wrap `man` and in cases where I've tried to look up the man page for a shell builtin, jump to the relevant section of the Bash man page. There might be a better way, but here's what I've got currently:

```
man () {
  case "$(type -t "$1")" in
    builtin)
      local pattern="^ *$1"

      if bashdoc_match "$pattern \+[-[]"; then
        command man bash | less --pattern="$pattern +[-[]"
      elif bashdoc_match "$pattern\b"; then
        command man bash | less --pattern="$pattern[[:>:]]"
      else
        command man bash
      fi
      ;;
    keyword)
      command man bash | less --hilite-search --pattern='^SHELL GRAMMAR$'
      ;;
    *)
      command man "$@"
      ;;
  esac
}

bashdoc_match() {
  command man bash | col -b | grep -l "$1" > /dev/null
}
```

Comment: Similar: [Unwanted ctrl+h in file saved from man's output](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/198457)

Comment: What operating system are you using? I'm sure the accepted answer is correct but IO couldn't reproduce this on my Arch Linux box. `man bash | grep NAME` works as expected.

Comment: @terdon I'm on macOS. I get this behavior with Bash 3.2 and 4.4.5

Comment: Just as an aside: if you detect  a builtin, you can just use the bash `help` command to get its information.

Comment: @Joe The problem is I often find the `help` results leave too much out. Check out `help complete` vs the `complete` section in `man bash`, for instance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you add a `| sed -n l` to that `tail` command, to show non-printable characters, you'll probably see something like:

```
N\bNA\bAM\bME\bE
```

That is, each character is written as `X` Backspace `X`. On modern terminals, the character ends up being written over itself (as Backspace aka BS aka `\b` aka `^H` is the character that moves the cursor one column to the left) with no difference. But in ancient tele-typewriters, that would cause the character to appear in bold as it gets twice as much ink.

Still, pagers like `more`/`less` do understand that format to mean bold, so that's still what `roff` does to output bold text.

Some man implementations would call `roff` in a way that those sequences are not used (or internally call `col -b -p -x` to strip them like in the case of the `man-db` implementation (unless the `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` environment variable is set)), and don't invoke a pager when they detect the output is not going to a terminal (so `man bash | grep NAME` would work there), but not yours.

You can use `col -b` to remove those sequences (there are other types (`_` BS `X`) as well for underline).

For systems using GNU `roff` (like GNU or FreeBSD), you can avoid those sequences being used in the first place by making sure the `-c -b -u` options are passed to `grotty`, for instance by making sure the `-P-cbu` options is passed to `groff`.

For instance by creating a wrapper script called `groff` containing:

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec /usr/bin/groff -P-cbu "$@"
```

That you put ahead of /usr/bin/groff in `$PATH`.

With macOS' `man` (also using GNU `roff`), you can create a `man-no-overstrike.conf` with:

```
NROFF /usr/bin/groff -mandoc -Tutf8 -P-cbu
```

And call `man` as:

```
man -C man-no-overstrike.conf bash | grep NAME
```

Still with GNU `roff`, if you set the `GROFF_SGR` environment variable (or don't set the `GROFF_NO_SGR` variable depending on how the defaults have been set at compile time), then `grotty` (as long as it's not passed the `-c` option) will use ANSI SGR terminal escape sequences instead of those BS tricks for character attributes. `less` understand them when called with the `-R` option.

FreeBSD's man calls `grotty` with the `-c` option unless you're asking for *colours* by setting the MANCOLOR variable (in which case `-c` is not passed to `grotty` and `grotty` reverts to the default of using ANSI SGR escape sequences there).

```
MANCOLOR=1 man bash | grep NAME
```

will work there.

On Debian, GROFF_SGR is not the default. If you do:

```
GROFF_SGR=1 man bash | grep NAME
```

however, because `man`'s stdout is not a terminal, it takes it upon itself to also pass a `GROFF_NO_SGR` variable to `grotty` (I suppose so it can use `col -bpx` to strip the BS sequences as `col` doesn't know how to strip the SGR sequences, even though it still does it with `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING`) which overrides our `GROFF_SGR`. You can do instead:

```
GROFF_SGR=1 MANPAGER='grep NAME' man bash
```

(in a terminal) to have the SGR escape sequences.

That time, you'll notice that some of those *NAME*s do appear in bold on the terminal (and in a `less -R` pager). If you feed the output to `sed -n l` (`MANPAGER='sed -n /NAME/l'`), you'll see something like:

```
\033[1mNAME\033[0m$
```

Where `\e[1m` is the sequence to enable bold in ANSI compatible terminals, and `\e[0m` the sequence to revert all SGR attributes to the default.

On that text `grep NAME` works as that text does contain `NAME`, but you could still have problems if looking for text where only parts of it is in bold/underline...

Comment: Wow, pretty interesting to see the legacy of physical tele-type there. Twice as much ink => bold. Makes perfect sense

Comment: I'm loving `sed -n l` as a substitute for `od`.

Answer (score 13):

If you look at any manual page, you'll notice that the headers are in bold. This is achieved through formatting them with control characters. To be able to `grep` like you're wanting to, these have to be stripped out.

The `col` utility may be used for this:

```
$ man bash | col -b | grep 'NAME'
```

The `-b` option has the following description [on OpenBSD](http://man.openbsd.org/col):

> Do not output any backspaces, printing only the last character
>                written to each column position.  This can be useful in
>                processing the output of mandoc(1).

---

Linux the `col` manual (on Ubuntu) doesn't have the last sentence in there (but it works in the same way).

On Linux, unsetting the `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` environment variable (or setting it to an empty string) may also help, and will allow you to `grep` without passing the output of `man` through `col -b`.

Comment: I think (as in I tested this on an Arch and an Ubuntu system) that on Linux this isn't necessary, or not anymore. On both systems, the `NAME` in the bash manual is just `NAME`, no `\b`.

Comment: @terdon I didn't spot the mentioning of macOS first, so I assumed a wrongly configured Linux system was a possibility. I have now trimmed off the Linux bits.

Comment: You missed nothing, I asked the OP what OS they're using because I couldn't reproduce on Linux, they said macOS and I just added it now. And I wasn't implying you were wrong, for all I know there are Linux distributions out there where the `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` variable works exactly as you say it does. I just wanted to point out that that isn't the case always.