# How to pipe a man page (without pagination) while intentionally preserving formatting?

Tags: bash, text-processing, pipe, man, pager

Minimal example:

```bash
man git | cat
```

Real example:

```bash
man git | grep --color=always -C 3 "pathspec"
```

FWIW, I've tried `--pager="cat"` using various pagers, as well as piping to various pagers. I've also tried using `vimcat` with the same, but unfortunately [it freezes](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager/issues/222). I've even tried using `unbuffered`. All to no avail.

Perhaps it's possible using `-T` or `{g,n,t}roff`, but I'm not sure how? Is there a way I can pipe to `less`/`vim`/etc and have it pass through to stdout **with formatting (colors/etc)** and **without paginating**?

---

---

---

**Edit:** Thanks to Stéphane's help below, I now have a beautiful way of easily searching through (and highlighting!) all matched man pages. This is a game changer for me. Thank you, Stéphane!

[image]

For those who might be interested, here is the key part of the script (no doubt it can be improved; feedback is always welcome):

**Edit:** I've now incorporated Stéphane's additional feedback. Huge improvement!

**Edit:** I've further improved this solution to work with both Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and macOS 12.6, [by instead piping to `ul`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717072/why-might-man-awk-be-including-results-that-dont-match-the-search-term/717080#717080).

```bash
#!/bin/bash
arg_search="$1"

typeset -A seen=()
while IFS= read -ru3 filename; do
    if (( ! seen[\$filename]++ )); then
        # 'man -awK' sometimes returns bogus results due to searching through
        # everything, including comments in the man source file, so filter
        # these out. Note that this creates a secondary problem: legitimate
        # results may get filtered out when the search term is two or more
        # words spanning across lines. This can be solved with a multiline
        # regex using `pcre2grep -M 'search\s+term`, but this is perhaps
        # growing beyond the scope of things here.
        { man --no-hyphenation --no-justification --regex -- "$filename" | \
            grep -iqE -- "$arg_search"; } || continue

        # Print filename. Fill terminal width with highlighted background color.
        filename_bar="$(printf '%s\t' "$filename" | expand -t $(tput cols))"
        printf '\e[1;103;30m%s\e[0m\n' "$filename_bar"
        # Per Stéphane's feedback, here's a cleaner version of the same for zsh:
        # psvar=${(mr[COLUMNS])filename} print -P '%K{yellow}%F{black}%1v%k%f'

        MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1 man \
            --no-hyphenation --no-justification --regex -- "$filename" | \
            ul | \
            grep -iE --color=always -- "$arg_search"
    fi
    # 'unbuffer' seems to be required for macOS in order to unbuffer the output,
    # as 'stdbuf -oL -eL' doesn't seem to work. Install on macOS using
    # 'brew install expect' [sic], which contains unbuffer. This otherwise
    # doesn't hurt anything on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Unbuffering the output of
    # 'man -awK' is important because it can take a long time to run.
done 3< <(unbuffer man -awK --regex -- "${arg_search}")
```

Comment: Not sure where do you see a freeze, but a simple `cat` or `/bin/cat` as a pager does a nice piping into `grep`:
`man --pager="cat" git | grep -C 3 "pathspec"`

Comment: Related: [Grep: unexpected results when searching for words in heading from man page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371062)

Comment: Why are you using process substitution + cat + a here-document instead of just having the commands that are inside the here document directly called by `bash -c`, i.e.. using `bash -c "foo"` instead of `bash -c "$(cat <<EOF foo; EOF; )"`?

Comment: @ed-morton No good reasons, only bad reasons. I'll edit this later to incorporate Stéphane's feedback and constructive criticism. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
GROFF_SGR=1 man -P 'grep --color=always -C 3 pathspec'  git
```

If piping to `grep`, you'll likely want `GROFF_SGR=1` (needed on Debian-based systems at least) for bold/underline to be implemented with ANSI SGR escape sequences (like `\e[1mBOLD\e[m`) instead of the traditional `B\bBO\bOL\bLD\bD` which would make it difficult to grep. See [Grep: unexpected results when searching for words in heading from man page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371062) for details.

Note that the pager (here `grep`) is only run if `man`'s stdout goes to a terminal. Piping to a command such as `less` would disable both that `grep` and the formatting.

Setting `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` used to disable SGR in my tests when I answered [Grep: unexpected results when searching for words in heading from man page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371062) back then, but it seems to no longer be the case (at least not on Ubuntu 20.04).

So, to use a pager, you could either do

```
GROFF_SGR=1 MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1 man git |
  grep --color=always -C 3 pathspec | less -R
```

Though as it's not started by `man`, `less` is not configured to display a relevant footer line, or you could pass an inline shell script to `-P` that calls `grep` and the `pager`.

For instance, with `zsh`:

```
mangrep()
  GROFF_SGR=1 CODE="
     grep --color=always -C3 ${(j[ ])${(qq)@[2,-1]}} | pager
  " man -P 'sh -c "eval \"$CODE\""' $1
```

And then for instance:

```
mangrep git -i pathspecs
```

If your `pager` is `less`, as it's started by `man`, it will inherit the `LESS*` environment variables that `man` sets which look like:

```
LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page git(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page git(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$
LESSCHARSET=utf-8
```

A bash (4.4+) equivalent could look like:

```
mangrep() {
  local page=$1 IFS=' '
  shift
  GROFF_SGR=1 CODE="
    grep --color=always -C3 ${*@Q} | pager
  " man -P 'bash -c "eval \"$CODE\""' ${page:+"$page"}
}
```

(using `"$*"` and `IFS=' '` instead of `j[ ]` to join with space, `@Q` (which requires `bash` for decoding) instead of `(qq)` (which does sh-compatible quoting), using `shift` and saving the first argument in `$page` as `@Q` can't be combined with array ranges).

To allow options for `man` (in `zsh`):

```
mangrep() {
  local page=$@[(i)[^-]*]
  GROFF_SGR=1 CODE="
     grep --color=always -C3 ${(j[ ])${(qq)@[page+1,-1]}} | pager
  " man -P 'sh -c "eval \"$CODE\""' "$@[1,page]"
}
```

And then for instance:

```
mangrep -a printf -i precision
```

To look for `precision` case `i`nsensitively (`-i` passed to `grep`) in `a`ll `printf` man pages (`-a` passed to `man`).

Make it a script instead of a function:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
page=$@[(i)[^-]*]
GROFF_SGR=1 CODE="
  grep --color=always -C3 ${(j[ ])${(qq)@[page+1,-1]}} | pager
  " exec man -P 'sh -c "eval \"$CODE\""' "$@[1,page]"
```

And then you'll be able to use from any shell (or non-shell), not just `zsh`.

---

Some comments on the code you posted in your edit:

[...]

> ```
> man -w -a -K "$arg_search" | \
> ```

Should be `man -w -a -K -- "$arg_search"` or you won't be able to search for things that start with `-` (other than using things like `arg_search='[-]-foo'` as a work around).

> ```
>     stdbuf -oL -eL uniq | \
> ```

`uniq` only removes duplicate if they are consecutive

> ```
>     xargs -d $'\n' -n 1 -I {} env bash -c "
> ```

`-I` and `-n 1` are redundant. Also, a `bash` inline script can take more than one argument, no need to call `bash` for each.

> ```
>         $(
>         cat <<EOF
> ```

As `EOF` is not quoted, expansions are being performed in the here doc and that's passed as the *shell code* argument. That is bad practice, that's a typical code injection vulnerability. The external data should be passed either as arguments or env variables instead.

> ```
>             filename='{}'
> ```

Same thing, the expansion (by `xargs`) of `{}` ends up in the shell code.

> ```
>             filename_length="\${#filename}"
>             terminal_width="$(tput cols)"
>             delta_length="\$(("\$terminal_width" - "\$filename_length"))"
>
>             # Print filename, and fill width with highlighted background color.
>             padding="\$(seq -s' ' "\$(("\$delta_length" + 1))" | \
>                 tr -d '[:digit:]')"
>             printf '\e[1;103;30m%s\e[0m' "\$filename\$padding"
> ```

Quite convoluted. I using `zsh`, that'd just be:

```
psvar=${(mr[COLUMNS])filename} print -P '%K{yellow}%F{black}%1v%k%f'
```

With other shells, you can also do right padding with of a string with:

```
printf '%s\t' "$string" | expand -t "$(tput cols)"
```

Which at least on BSDs and like zsh's `r`ight padding expansion flag when used with the `m` flag takes into account the display width of each character (escape sequences not supported though, so the colouring ones must not be included in the text sent to `expand`).

> ```
>             GROFF_SGR=1 man --no-hyphenation --no-justification \
>                 "\$filename" | grep --color=always "$arg_search"
> ```

[...]

I suppose you have `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING` defined? Without it, the formatting should be lost when piping to `grep`.

Also note that `man -K` does a fixed-string search and an extended regexp search with `--regex` and in either case is case insensitive, so you'd need the `-i` option and either add `--regex` to `man` and `-E` to `grep` or add `-F` to `grep` for the search logic to match between the two.

So, here,  I'd rather do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
ere=${1-GROFF_NO_SGR}
typeset -A seen=()
while IFS= read -ru3 filename; do
  if (( ! seen[\$filename]++ )); then
    psvar=${(mr[COLUMNS])filename} print -P '%K{yellow}%F{black}%1v%k%f'
    GROFF_SGR=1 MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1 man --no-hyphenation \
      --no-justification -l "$filename" |
      grep -iF --color=always -C4 -- "$ere"
  fi
done 3< <(man -awK -- "$ere")
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you very much, Stéphane! GROFF_SGR=1 was the missing piece to this puzzle! Before you answered, I was looking at the man-db source in frustration to understand why MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1 wasn't working either, but after reading your other answer and your `| sed -n l` suggestion therein, I now see that the formatting was being retained, but it was just not in SGR format. Is this why my console still wasn't displaying colors when using MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1? You seem to be an expert in this domain... How did you know about or first discover GROFF_SGR? Thanks again.

Comment: I don't  remember how I came across `GROFF_SGR` initially. Looks like it may be a Debian-only thing as SGR seems to be the default these days but Debian (at least) reverts to NO_SGR for man pages unless you set that env var. See /etc/groff/{man,mdoc}.local` there. See also https://bugs.debian.org/963490

Comment: @JonathanWheeler looks like Debian started disabling SGR in https://salsa.debian.org/debian/groff/-/commit/7c138b8c911756f3374e85827b66c8fa9f280483 in 2005 presumably when groff/grotty added colour support and made it the default, likely breaking all sorts of things initially.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler, see edit with comments on the code you added in your later edit.

Comment: Amazing feedback! Thank you, Stéphane! I'm working to incorporate it now. You're correct: MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING was accidentally still defined from my previous efforts. Also, I can no longer precisely remember why, but although zsh is "nicer" in so many ways, I remember that I was having difficulty getting scripts to interact nicely with one another for various reasons, particularly when sharing variables (and specifically arrays, which zsh seems much better at handling), so all of my scripts are simply in bash for consistency. That said, would you happen to have a bash version of your feedback?

Comment: Bonus points if you can also get this working on the latest version of macOS, if it's even possible. (I'm indeed running Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04, but also macOS 12.5.1.) Getting scripts to also play nicely on macOS is often a pain, even after installing gnu coreutils, etc. (All of my environments are shared and synced via Syncthing.)

**EXAMPLE:**
GROFF_SGR=1 man -P "egrep --color=always -C 4 -- 'GROFF_NO_SGR'" grotty

**RESULT:**
mandoc: /usr/share/man/man1/grotty.1:20:2: UNSUPP: unsupported roff request: do

Comment: I'm left scratching my head again, because for some reason `man -awK` is including many results that don't appear anywhere in the man page. For example, the first result returned for `man -awK -- "typeset"` is `/usr/share/man/man1/lcf.1.gz`, but typeset doesn't appear anywhere within `man lcf`, nor `man lcf | sed -n l`.

Comment: Stéphane, `uniq` seems to suffice because `man -awK -- "$ere"` seems to indeed only ever return multiple *consecutive* duplicates. (If so, `uniq` may theoretically be faster as O(seen^2) grows large, though in practice, this probably doesn't matter.) However, all of your feedback is well taken; I'm working to incorporate it.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler, the `while read... (( !seen))` handles both stdbuf an uniq.

Comment: Note that `-K` is case insensitive, so we'd need to add `-i` to `grep` as well, I'll edit that in.

Comment: I don't use macos nor have I access to a machine running macos so can't help you much there.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler, hash lookups don't grow with o(n²), they're pretty much o(1) even if more expensive than `uniq`, but I agree `uniq` is sufficient. Bottleneck is likely to be `man -K` which is very expensive

Comment: My answer was also incorrect regarding `man -K` doing ERE search. See edit.

Comment: Wow, you're really teaching me a lot. Thank you! So `(( ! seen[\$filename]++ ))` is working as a hash lookup and not as an array? (I didn't even realize bash had hash sets/maps!) Can you please break this line down for me, including why `\$` is escaped, and the post-increment, or perhaps point me to a resource for the same?

Comment: @JonathanWheeler see [How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627474)

Answer (score 2):

The only method I've discovered that works with both **macOS 12.6** *and* **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS** is quite simply the following:

```bash
MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1 man git | ul
```

(I'm leaving Stéphane Chazelas' answer as the accepted answer, since it is far more detailed, and as a thanks for lending his substantial time and expertise.)