# groff -mandoc creating "ESC[1m" versus overstriking with backspace for bold text

Tags: terminal, unicode, escape-characters, groff

I found that groff uses different ways to indicate bold text for the `utf8` output format.

On FreeBSD 14, groff emits escape codes for a terminal (ESC, `[1m`):

```
$ printf ".Dd today\n.Sh NAME\n" | groff -mandoc -Tutf8 | od -c
0000000   \n 033   [   1   m   N   A   M   E 033   [   0   m  \n
[...]
```

On Linux (debian Bookworm) is uses backspaces and overstriking:

```
$ printf ".Dd today\n.Sh NAME\n" | groff -mandoc -Tutf8 | od -c
[...]
0000120   N  \b   N   A  \b   A   M  \b   M   E  \b   E  \n
```

Why is it so and is there a way to make Linux groff also use ESC codes for the terminal? I have read the groff man page from top to bottom but can't find an option to change this behavior.

(I need to post-process the result and ESC codes make that much easier and flexible.)

**EDIT**: The solution (thanks go to @egmont) was to read Debian's grotty(1) manual and then force the SGR behavior with

```
printf ".Dd today\n.Sh NAME\n" | GROFF_SGR=y groff -mandoc -Tutf8
```

Comment: See also [Grep: unexpected results when searching for words in heading from man page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371067)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian Bookworm configures groff 1.22 for the old backspace-overwrite behavior you see there, and documents it in their patched `grotty` manual page along with how to revert to the newer SGR (`\e[1m`-like) behavior:

```
printf ".Dd today\n.Sh NAME\n" | GROFF_SGR=y groff -mandoc -Tutf8
```

It seems that the given configuration and patch is no longer there in their groff 1.23 package in `unstable`, as well as in Ubuntu 23.04. So it's probably the last Debian version you see with this old behavior, they're switching to the new SGR method, following upstream groff's defaults.

Comment: grotty(1), if only I had looked there. Thanks, accepted!

Comment: Don't blame yourself, haha, it would have never occurred to me either. I just knew Debian had this config or patch, I looked at their package to see how it went exactly and found the manpage patch :)

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse `script` and `less` to convert the backspace sequences:

```
script --return --quiet -c "printf '.Dd today\n.Sh NAME\n' | groff -mandoc -Tutf8 | less" /dev/null | od -c

…
0000200   1   m   N   A   M   E 033   [   0   m 033   [   m  \r  \n
```

Comment: Turns out, `printf ".Dd today\n.Sh NAME\n" | GROFF_SGR=y groff -mandoc -Tutf8` can work around Debian's hack.